# rails 4 modelname_params doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a contact form in Rails 4 and Ruby 2. I've added a Model and migrated it with DB and then I made the form etc, but this code gives an error.

```
@newSupport = Support.new(support_params)
AdminMailer.contact_email(@newSupport.name, @newSupport.email, @newSupport.subject, @newSupport.message).deliver
```

Rails debugger says that:

```
undefined local variable or method `support_params' for #<MainController:0x007f9f8a0dcb28>
```

Why is my support_params undefined? Where can I define it? I didn't scaffold it, but when I scaffold, I saw that we can easily link the form values with the variable in controller via "modelname_params", but in this case it is undefined.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wanting you to use strong_parameters (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) to sanitize your params in the controller.

Not sure why it is undefined, but it should be defined in the controller as a private method.

```
private

#assuming you're using params[:support]
def support_params
  params.require(:support).permit(:attributes, :you, :want, :to, :allow)
end
```